# Set activity screen orientation using styles

Tags: android, android-activity, themes, screen-orientation

I'm trying to set activity screen orientation using a styles:

Here is the styles.xml:

```
...
<style name="Some.Activity" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
...
```

and here is activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="SomeActivity" android:theme="@style/Some.Activity"/>
```

and it doesn't work.
I know that I can just set

```
<activity android:name="SomeActivity" android:theme="@style/Some.Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="..."/>
```

in the manifest, but its important to me to do that using a theme.
Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This link may help. Basically you have to make different layout files for each orientation and put them in corresponding layout-land or layout-port folders. You can also create layouts for different orientations on different screen sizes. For example, if not all of the controls you have for a "normal" sized screen in landscape mode fit on a small screen you can create a folder named layout-small-land and have another customized layout file.