# An Android orientation glitch?

Tags: android, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I believe to have stumbled upon an inherent glitch in the orientation handling of Android.

I have an activity A

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

No sensor implies that the Activity A won't be affected by the physical device rotation.

I also have an activity B which has an overridden onSaveInstanceBundle

```
/*Will be called before orientation change*/
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);
      currentState.putBoolean(ApplicationConstants.Messages.ORIENTATION_CHANGED , true);
      currentState.putBoolean("RESTART", true);

      currentState.putString(ApplicationConstants.Messages.CURRENT_LANGUAGE,currentLocale);

    }
```

onSaveInstance is always called when the orientation of the screen is changed.
Like A, B also has the following under onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

Now here comes the conundrum.

I press a button from A, which is programmed to invoke B while I am holding the device in normal portrait mode. I have a breakpoint attached to onSaveInstance

As expected, onSaveInstance is not called when B is invoked

However, here is a strange fact. If I hold the device in landscape mode, and then invoke B, B's onSaveInstance is invoked, and as the program is suspended upon the breakpoint, we can see that the device screen has landscaped.

Hence even though I have NO SENSOR argument on the activity, the sensor is in fact still working. And between an activity switch IF DONE WHILE WE HOLD THE DEVICE IN LANDSCAPE, the target activity starts in landscape. After I let the breakpoint go, B resumes to portrait view.

I have a long story as to why this is affecting a project that I am developing. I wished to know if anyone has any insights into this situation.

To sum up, my question is:

Is it true that during an activity switch, the Android system ignores the specified orientation, and by default uses the device's physical position? I can't set the orientation in the androidManifest. I have noted this is not the case if we put the orientation mode in the manifest.

Comment: The system does not know that activity B is special until it is started and executes the `setRequestedOrientation` call. So the described behaviour seems OK to me.

Comment: This solution worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381441/7826494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Leaving the below for reference, but this clearly does **NOT** actually work. :(

---

> He wants the application to be locked to portrait on cellphones, and
>   be free to rotate on tablets.

Ugh. Well, you actually can accomplish this through the manifest. How you do it depends on what you want to define as a "tablet". Let's assume the cutoff is the Google-suggested `sw600dp` (smallest width of 600dp is a good breakpoint for a 7" tablet).

You can make the following file structure in your `res` folder:

```
res
    - values
        - styles.xml
    - values-sw600dp
        - styles.xml
```

In your `values/styles.xml` (this will be your non-tablet style), define the following styles for your `Activity`:

```
<!-- This will be a base style that will affect both tablet and non-tablet -->
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="{{pick a base theme here -- e.g. Theme.Light}}"/>

<!-- This is the local style that will be used on devices whose smallest width
     is less than 600dp -->
<style name="BaseTheme.Activity">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
```

In your `values-sw600dp/styles.xml`:

```
<!-- This is the local style that will be used on devices whose smallest
     width is greater than or equal to 600dp. We define nothing here other
     than the fact that the style exists, so it will have the default screen
     orientation - that is, it will rotate freely. -->
<style name="BaseTheme.Activity"/>
```

Now, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside your `activity` tag, add:

```
android:theme="@style/BaseTheme.Activity"
```

And you should have the desired result. However, you should first remove all of the Java code you added to try to manage this yourself, as it will likely conflict with this causing unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks kcoppock . This is flawless and what I need

Comment: @kcoppock I just found out that your suggestion isn't simple . As in I found out that we need to seperate the layouts into layout-port folders etc for this to work ? I found this out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113923/set-activity-screen-orientation-using-styles

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib No, you should not have to do that. The style in values will be referenced for ANY screen whose smallest width is less than 600dp (or is older than Android 3.2).

Comment: <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>

        <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>

    </style>

I just tried this simple style . My screen has a blue background but the device is not being locked into portrait :S

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib And you removed all of your Java orientation code? (i.e. no calls to `setRequestedOrientation()` or any traces of `android:configChanges` in your manifest?)

Comment: @kcoppock exactly :( . Nothing hardcoded in my activity regarding the orientation . I googled this and found many announcing that they are not able to apply screen orientation using themes

Comment: Oh shoot. No that makes perfect sense actually. `screenOrientation` is an `activity` attribute, not a theme attribute. I might have another answer shortly.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to do this through styles. `screenOrientation` is an internal styleable enum, and I don't know of any way (although there should be) to internalize that into a resource that can be referenced in the manifest. :(

Comment: @kcoppock. I appreciate you taking time out to help . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Is it true that during an activity switch , the android system ignores the specified orientation , and by default uses the device's physical position ? .

That's not exactly true, because you are *not* specifying an orientation. `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR` just means "ignore the sensor from now on and keep it in the current orientation". That doesn't get called until `onCreate()` runs. Nowhere are you saying "lock into portrait from the very start".

> I can't set the orientation in the androidmanifest . I have noted this is not the case if we put the orientation mode in the manifest.

Out of curiousity, why can't you? That's the most common way to do it:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The reason it locks in correctly with the manifest entries is that the ActivityManager knows it should be locked in before the Activity is ever run.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I cannot set it in the manifest because my application is weird. Or rather my client is . He wants the application to be locked to potrait on cellphones , and be free to rotate on tablets. So if i set it in the manifest, i wont be able to dynamically change the layout from my code .

Comment: Geobits . can we do something to acheive the "lock into potrait from the very start" behaviour , other than the manifest?

Comment: You could make an PhoneActivity stub that extends your Activity class to deal with phones, and lock that one in the manifest. I'm sure there are other ways to handle it, that's just the first off the top of my head.

Comment: But no, other than the manifest, there's not really a place to put code to lock it in before it starts.

Comment: I can't absolutely let an activity orient after it has started for reasons that are not in scope of the question . So I believe I will make two applications . one for tabs ,one for devices. It kills me to do so but I think I have ran out of options

Comment: My basic problem is that if the device orients , it results in a configuration change. If you have been working on android you know about the shit support for multilingual applications . I dont understand why has Google discouraged as to make a multilingual application that is not bound by the language of the device itself. Rather just like in iphone , we should have support for in-application language switching . To acheive this I have written some dirty hacks .If i let my activity orient , it loses the current language and falls back to the default configuration

Comment: It sounds like those are some dirty hacks indeed. Have you tried using kcoppock's solution?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Language switching works perfectly if you don't resort to hacks like `configChanges` to handle configuration changes. If it's not working, that's on you.