# Can we give a screen orientation attribute of an activity as a style?

Tags: java, android

Folks .

Can we give a screenorientation attribute of an activity as a style ?

for example

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.evento.mofa.activities.AttestationInformation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_attestation_information"
        android:theme="@styles/mystyle"
         >

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"><item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
```

The styles is under values/styles.xml

Actually its not working with me

Comment: are you saying you want to use styleA in portrait and styleB in landscape?

Comment: @Eluvatar. I plan use the value/style (portrait) . and the value-sw600dp/style(portrait/landscape) . In short I would want my application to be free to move on a tablet , but fixed to portrait on a cellphone . This was suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903462/an-android-orientation-glitch/18903868?noredirect=1#comment27906075_18903868 marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this from the code. You can get the display metrics from

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

and you can set the orientation in `onCreate` of the activity using `setRequestedOrientation` from the `Activity` class.